# Rails 4 Minitest tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, minitest

I don't know if this question has been asked before so please let me know if it's the case.

Does Minitest support tagging test cases so I don't have to run all the tests every time or run a specific group of tests together (or skip some)?

I DO NOT want to use the following:

`ruby -Itest test/lib/foo/bar_test.rb --name=test_bar_should_be_delicious`

It would be great to have something like the above with a `--tag` or `--only` that's being used with Minitest.I could probably monkey patch it but I want to know if there's something that exists already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have several options. First, you can run a specific test file using the rails test task:

```
$ rake test test/lib/foo/bar_test.rb
```

That will run all the tests in the file. If you want to run a specific test, you can add the [minitest-line](https://github.com/judofyr/minitest-line) gem which enables specifying the line of the test you want to run. This gem requires Minitest 5, so you will need to be on rails 4.1+.

```
$ ruby -Itest test/lib/foo/bar_test.rb -l 12
```

I don't know if this works with the rails test task or not, so you may have to do something like this:

```
$ rake test test/lib/foo/bar_test.rb TESTOPTS="-l 12"
```

Another option that I think it easier is to use the [minitest-focus](https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest-focus) gem. You simply annotate the test you want to run with `focus` and it will run just that test. You don't need to mess with any command-line arguments.

```
class Foo::BarTest < Minitest::Test
  focus
  def test_bar_should_be_delicious
    assert "delicious"
  end
end
```

And then run the tests as you would normally run them.

```
$ rake test
```

Comment: `minitest-focus` seems to do it for my current needs, thanks! :-)